# Python:How to change the position in the file from current file position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I want to change the file position from the current file position to another position.Suppose my current file position is 13 and I want to change this file position to the 18.
I use the `seek()` method as follow but it shows some error.

**Code:-**

```
fileobj = open("intro.txt","r");
content = fileobj.read(13);
pos = fileobj.tell();
print("Current position : ",pos);
fileobj.seek(5,1); #Change position from current position to next five character.
```

**Error**

```
fileobj.seek(5,1);

io.UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks
```

I use python 3.4.3.How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works in Python 2, but not in 3.  You must open the file as binary:

```
fileobj = open("intro.txt","rb");
```

Comment: But in "rb" mode we can't write into the file...